# $b\geq-\frac{a^2}{c},\space \forall c>0$ and $b\leq-\frac{a^2}{c},\space \forall c<0$ $\Rightarrow$ $b=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let$\space$ $0\neq a,b,c\in\Bbb R$.

then if

$b\geq-\frac{a^2}{c},\space \forall c>0$

and

$b\leq-\frac{a^2}{c},\space \forall c<0$

follows $b=0\space$?

I've got into this one while trying to prove another theory, if i wasn't clear enough, let me know and i will update my question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- It holds that $0$ is the supremum of the set $\{ -\frac{a^2}{c}: c \in \mathbb R^+\}.$ We have that $b$ is an upper bound for the set, thus, $b\ge 0.$
- Also, it holds that $0$ is the infimum of the set $\{-\frac{a^2}{c}: c\in \mathbb R^-\}.$ Thus, $b\le 0$.

Thus, we have that
$$0 \le b \le 0 \implies b = 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

$b \ge -\frac {a^2}c \forall c >0 \iff -b \le -\frac{a^2}{-c} \forall c > 0 \iff -b \le \frac{a^2}{c} \forall c > 0$.

But we also have $b \le -\frac{a^2}{c} \forall c < 0 \iff b \le \frac{a^2}{c} \forall c > 0$

So $|b| \le \frac{a^2}{c} \forall c > 0$

As $\frac{a^2}{c} > 0; \lim_{c\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a^2}{c} = 0$

Then, yes, it follows $b = 0$